# Restoring backup of wordpress website on LAMP

Tags: backup

I have a WordPress site with LAMP. Since I moved to a new apartment the site does not display well anymore, and I cannot access its dashboard through `http://websiteurl.com/wp-admin`.

Since I had backed the site up (with updraftplus, FIY) I was trying to do a clean wordpress install and restore the backup. During the installation process should I use the same database of the site I am trying to restore - thus setting the same  same `DB_NAME`, `DB_USER`, `DB_PASSWORD` and `DB_HOST` - or make a new one?

Note: in the old place I had a fixed public IP, so my domain (`http://mywebsite.com`) pointed to that. After I moved to the new place I had to set up a Dynamic DNS service, so now my domain points to that service's url (`http://mywebsite.ddns.com`). Users can still access the website through the domain address (`http://mywebsite.com`). I wonder if that is relevant to why I can access the website but not the admin dashboard.